# finding XML node name structure in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have an ugly druple-gardens RSS feed coming into flash and I'm using the same idea as this link. http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/accessing-views-from-flash-in-drupal-gardens to parse it into a new xml structure.

flash code:

```
            var str = item.description;
            var newString = str.split("&lt;").join("<").split("&gt;").join(">").split("&quot;`").join("\"").split("&nbsp;").join(" ");
            var description = new XML('<description>'+ newString + '</description>');

            trace("myXML = "+description[0]);
```

I'm trying to see how I can get to each element by names. Here is the first description node.
traced out description xml.

```
<description>
  <div class="field field-name-field-hometown field-type-text field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">Home Town:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">Bemidji, Minnesota (up near where they filmed Fargo)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-school field-type-text field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">School:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">UCONN Undergrad / Columbia MBA</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-lives field-type-text field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">Currently Live:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">Milford, CT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-relationship field-type-text field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">relationship status:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">Married with two boys</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-tidbit field-type-text-long field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">tidbit:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">I’m an avid UCONN fan, a Green Bay Packers shareholder and I golf whenever I get the chance.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-favorite-memory field-type-text-long field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">Favorite Memory:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">beating Worthington in the Ping Pong Tournament</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</description>
```

I have tried to get to field-label with no luck. 
Example:

description.div.field-label and the value of the field items

Anyone have any idea how I can get to the elements using the names in the above xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
var list:XMLList =yourXML.descendents('div').(attribute('class')=='field-label');
for each var (node:XML in list) {
   trace(node.text());
}
```

?

Comment: Hi Amy how would I get to the image node in this. <div class="field-items">
  <div class="field-item even">
    <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://blsa.drupalgardens.com/sites/blasa.drupalgardens.com/files/time_0.png" width="525" height="700" alt=""/>
  </div>